# Add filter condition to Dojo ComboBox

Tags: combobox, dojo

I have a dijit/form/ComboBox control that has a JsonStore as a object store.

```
// Prepare the datasource for combobox
settings.JsonStore = new JsonRestStore({ target: settings.dataUrl });
settings.ObjectStore = new ObjectStore({ objectStore: settings.JsonStore });

var ComboBox = new ComboBox({
    id: settings.id,
    name: settings.id,
    value: settings.value,
    style: {
        width: settings.width.value + 'px',
        display: (settings.visible) ? 'visible' : 'none'
    },
    maxHeight: settings.dropHeight.value,
    store: settings.ObjectStore,
    searchAttr: settings.comboValue,
    labelType: "html",
    labelFunc: function (item, store) {
        var labelText = '....';
        return labelText;
    },
    onChange: function (evt) {
    }
}
```

When I try to query the combobox, the following http request are made:

```
http://<settings.dataUrl>/?<settings.comboValue>?A*
http://<settings.dataUrl>/?<settings.comboValue>?AB*
```

I would like to know if I can add a filter on the combobox based on the value of another control. Like for example:

```
http://<settings.dataUrl>/?CustomerNo=0001&<settings.comboValue>?AB*
```

I already tried the following, I tried to change the store of the combobox when the filter is changed by changing the url. But it does not work. I tried to reset the store by setting the store value again, and it causes error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am finally able to get the answer thru another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109026/searchattr-combobox-array).

```
Combobox.set( 'query', { 'CustomerNo' : dijit.byId('<Customer control ID>').getValue() } );
```

The query becomes:

```
http://<settings.dataUrl>/?CustomerNo=0001&<settings.comboValue>?AB*
```

Comment: Thanks for self answering.